# Do you lose reputation when someone comments on your question?

Tags: discussion, reputation, comments

Recently I asked a question on serverfault and someone commented on it, i also saw that at about the same time I lose 2 reputation points.

Do you lose reputation when someone comments? (Which sorta makes sense)

**UPDATE** The reason I thought it makes sense, is because usually someone only has to comment when you're question was not clear enough, or when it didn't have enough info. Since it's bad of you to leave vague questions that need explaining, I thought you'd lose rep.

Comment: How would that make sense?

Comment: They were being nice by leaving you the comment when they downvoted

Comment: Something tells me Rory has never heard of Occam's razor.

Comment: Welbog: Maybe he's not allowed to play with sharp things without supervision.

Comment: sorry for taking your rep, forgive me

Comment: @Welbog: *post hoc ergo propter hoc*  It's in Latin, so it must be science.

Comment: @Pesto: *Quid quid latine dictum sit, altum videtur.*

Comment: @mmyers: Ooooh, that's a much longer sentence.  It must be even more profound!

Comment: @Pesto Si hoc signum legere potes, operis boni in rebus Latinus alacribus et fructuosis potiri potes!

Comment: I updated the question explaining my reasoning

Answer (score 13, accepted):

He downvoted you and left a comment explaining it. They are not related. You can downvote without commenting and comment without downvoting. One does not cause the other.

> (Which sorta makes sense)

You're going to have to explain what horrible confusion of ideas leads you to believe that commenting should remove reputation because I'm afraid I can't fathom how anyone could come up with something like that.

Comment: +1 For using the word fathom in an extremely nice way :)

Comment: @Diago: +1 for using words. You know how much I like words.

Comment: I am commenting in the hopes that you lose rep.

Comment: But I want to comment on your comment PEsto, in hopes that YOU will lose rep.

Comment: @Chacha102: I once lost rep right after eating a cheeseburger.  Maybe you should give me a cheeseburger.

Comment: @Chacha102: Oh yeah that happened to me once, too, except it was with a baconburger and a side of onion rings. For some reason when I ate it Pesto lost four and one thirds rep! We could try that again.

Comment: @Welbog the operative word here is "sorta" :P

Comment: @pageman: It doesn't "sorta" make sense, either.

Answer (score 3):

The comment system has no impact on reputation. Often user's may leave a comment if they downvote you, but this is not required. Without looking for the actual post, it seems likely this is what happened, since you say you lost 2 which is the effect of being downvoted.